# How to write a custom resolver for a multi-brand website?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a situation where a `th:replace` needs to be conditionally resolved based on whether a brand-specific file exists.

The current code is simple:

```
<!--/* brand.menuLogo has been pre-resolved to point to some specific file */-->
<div th:replace="${brand.menuLogo}"></div>
```

But this is less than satisfactory, for a number of reasons, and it's hard to maintain.

I would like to be able to do this instead:

```
<!--/* brand.id has some value like 'X' for Brand X */-->
<div th:replace="somefile_${brand.id}"></div>
```

With the idea that if `somefile_X.html` exists it will be used, otherwise `somefile.html` will be used instead.

What's the cleanest, easiest, most readable and most maintainable way to accomplish this in Thymeleaf? I'm open-minded to any solution that works "the Thymeleaf way" whatever that is. I used the term "custom resolver" in the question as a pre-conceived notion of how it might work, but I'm not beholden to such concept.

*CLARIFICATION*

The site has hundreds of files, and not every file has a variation for every brand. I'm interested in a mechanism that can resolve the correct file based on a combination of naming convention and existence of the file. So if FILE_X exists it is chosen, otherwise FILE is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **ternary expression** in `th:replace` value like the following:

```
<div th:replace="${brand.id} ? 'somefile' + __${brand.id}__ + '.html' : 'somefile.html'">
```

Please note that `__${brand.id}__` is preprocessed by thymeleaf engine as noted in this [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing).

Comment: Thanks. I added a clarification to explain why this answer is not satisfactory.